# Service file don't see /home/user files and folders - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, services

I make service file, vaultwarden.service to look like this (here showing just part of it):

```
# The user/group vaultwarden is run under. the working directory (see below) should allow write and read access to this user/group
User=vaultwarden
Group=vaultwarden
# The location of the compiled binary
ExecStart=/home/vaultwarden/vaultwarden   # user is vaultwarden, binary vaultwarden
```

When in service file part look like code above, I got error
`vaultwarden.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/vaultwarden/vaultwarden: Permission denied`

But when just copy binary file  `vaultwarden` to `/usr/bin/vaultwarden` it work's. I don't know what's the problem, is there some issue or rule, which says that can't in service file do path's in home folder of some user? I am read all related links and post, and try it all, and still have the same issue.

P.S. Access right are good, I even the whole home folder of vaultwarden user change ownership to 777, even change to root owner (in case that root should run binary, but 777 should resolve issue...)

Any clues?

Comment: I want binaries, ```WorkingDirectory```, ```ReadWriteDirectories``` to be in home folder of the user, not on some other location. How to accomplish that? Because when I do that, i got errors as I mention it

Answer (score 0):

In my service file, also was these lines:

```
PrivateDevices=true
ProtectHome=true
```

Those parameters don't allow manipulation with home folder. It should be commented or deleted from the service file.